# Error in Dropbox file download using WebClient

Tags: download, webclient, dropbox

I am working on downloading a text file hosted in dropbox. But i am getting a 400 Error code in the Completed function. I find the problem is with the dropbox hosted files only. I could download other sample text files hosted such as "http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt".

Below is the code snippet i am using for downloading a text file from dropbox.

```
void downloadFile()
{
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
NetworkCredential Credentials = new NetworkCredential(<username>, <password>, "<domain>);
webClient.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
webClient.Proxy.Credentials = Credentials;
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(<downloadfileurl>, @"C:\test.txt");
}

private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Successfully downloaded");
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
    }
}
```

The following is the error am getting :

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)

   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

Any support to tweak this problem will be highly appreciated.

Note : I have also tried using the WebRequest(POST), but same error there also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use some sort of username/password authentication to download the file? Dropbox doesn't support any such thing.

You didn't share the URL you're trying to download. If it's a share link (a link created by a user who shared a file), it should just work with no authentication. If it's a file that hasn't been shared, you'll need to access it via the Dropbox API. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers to start learning about the Dropbox API.